# Is there in git information about builds and releases like it is in tfvc

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I'm trying to migrate from TFS to Git because tfs support stops.
In tfs I requested information about changesets, releases and builds because I needed that for detailed verie information about the different versions of our program.
(with api calls like this: [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{..}/{..}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7B..%7D/%7B..%7D/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0))
This information is not (just) available in git. I can't find it anyway

The changeset information is more or less available by querying the commits of a repository's pushes ([https://dev.azure.com/{..}/{..}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}](https://dev.azure.com/%7B..%7D/%7B..%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D) /pushes/{pushId}). I succeeded.

But is there anything in git that is similar to the builds and releases in tfs?
I've been searching for hours, but probably in the wrong place :-(

Does anyone know if this information can be retrieved and if so, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, not in Git itself. Most of the *hosting sites*, however, add stuff like that.

Comment: Builds and/or releases (i.e. pipelines) are a separate concept that are not directly related to anything in version control, regardless of version control platform. I'm not sure what you're looking for. You can still release application code from Git using pipelines.